# Using querystrings in an iframe HTML

Tags: javascript, html, query-string

I have an iframe source with height and width values that needs to change according to a query string Like this:

`<iframe width="(value1)" height="(value2)" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://mips.tv/embedplayer/test121/1/(value1)/(value2)"></iframe>`

And I want the url like this:

```
mywebpage.com/something.html?width=(value1)&height=(value2)
```

Please help me, I´ve been looking for it for weeks

Comment: Can you use php, or only javascript? Can you use jQuery?

Comment: HTML, jquery and javascript, I dont have a php server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can only use javascript, then use this function to read the width and height values:

```
// return value of key_str variables query string of url
// Example: url = "index.html?alert=5&page=index"; if key_str = "alert" then it returns "5"
function getQuery(key_str) {
    if(window.location.search) {
        var query = window.location.search.substr(1);
        var pairs = query.split("&");
        for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
           var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
           if (unescape(pair[0]) == key_str) return unescape(pair[1]);
        }
      return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can easily use jQuery/javascript to adjust the attributes of the iFrame: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2.

EDIT:  OK, try this. Give your iFrame a name ('myiframe' in the example below):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function getQuery(key_str) {
    if(window.location.search) {
        var query = window.location.search.substr(1);
        var pairs = query.split("&");
        for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
           var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
           if (unescape(pair[0]) == key_str) return unescape(pair[1]);
        }
      return null;
    }
}

var width = getQuery('width');
var height = getQuery('height');
var src = 'http://mips.tv/embedplayer/test121/1/' + width + '/' + height;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var f = $('iframe[name=myiframe]');
    f.attr({
          'width'  : width,
          'height' : height,
          'src'    : src
      }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: It´s not working, check: http://redzeronline.ucoz.com/test1.html?width=900&height=450

Comment: @Xcite: The above is just a function!  You must also write the script that calls the function and adjusts the iFrame attributes.  (Also, you must add type="text/javascript" in your script tag.)

Comment: Excuse me i'm a noob :( but look what happens:
http://redzeronline.ucoz.com/test1.html?width=600&height=500 It changes the size of the iframe but not the values of the src